# indicator-cpufreq disappearing from top bar

Tags: cpu

When I run `indicator-cpufreq` it shows the icon but when I leave the terminal it removes it. How can I make it permanent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Unity) Press Alt+F2, type `indicator-cpufreq` and click on the matching result. No terminal needed.

To have the `indicator-cpufreq` program run at startup (so you don't need to start it yourself), go to Startup Applications (`gnome-session-properties`), and on the right hand side where you have `Add`, `Remove`, `Edit`, click `Add`. Make the name and description whatever you want, but make the command box contain `indicator-cpufreq`.

Edit: The default entry in startup applications for `indicator-cpufreq` is this:

- Name: `CPU Frequency Scaling Indicator`
- Command: `indicator-cpufreq`
- Description: `An indicator for monitoring and switching CPU frequency scaling`

Comment: I can confirm that XFCE (Desktop Environment of XUbuntu) has the same functionality, it just looks a bit different. Probably all Ubuntu derivates use this Alt+F2 to launch a command... (?)

Comment: but when i reboot it disappears again. any idea ?

Comment: @Ivaylo edited. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make a file in your home folder called whatever.sh and paste in to it

```
indicator-cpufreq
```

Save it, right click it and choose preferences then permissions and check allow executing file as a program

Now open files (nautilus) and go to edit, preferences then behavior and check "run executable text files when they are opened"

Now you can just double click the .sh to run the indicator.

This works well I tested it.

Comment: I would prefer creating either a full .desktop launcher or a full bash script with a hashbang, but that's my opinion...